# Using vlQt4::Qt4Widget inside a Qt Layout

Tags: qt, opengl, widget, visualization

i'm playing with Qt and [visualization library](http://visualizationlibrary.com/). I've tested the code [founded here](http://visualizationlibrary.com/documentation/pag_guide_rotating_cube.html) and it works great but i'm not able to insert the vlQt4::Qt4Widget widget into a QHBoxLayout instance created with designer. I have to say that i'm a Qt newbie maybe it's something very simple that i don't undestand.
Anyway starting from the [example above](http://visualizationlibrary.com/documentation/pag_guide_rotating_cube.html) i'm trying to insert the widget using this line

`ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(qt4_window, 1, Qt::AlignHCenter);`

but i can't see anything. The other problem is this line (taken from the [example above](http://visualizationlibrary.com/documentation/pag_guide_rotating_cube.html))

`qt4_window->addEventListener(applet.get());`

If this line is uncommented my program crash. Is there any example of application using [visualization library](http://visualizationlibrary.com/) and Qt ? where is my error ?

Thanks a lot